# в исходное состояние

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

при старте сцены запускается таймер. По истечении времени таймер выгружает сцену.
По ходу игры приходится перезапускать сцену(чтобы все вернулось в исходное состояние). При этом таймер обнуляется.
Как это сделать, чтобы таймер и набранные очки не обнулялись?

Comment: `static` объявить

Comment: Можно чуть подробнее? Я даже не понял о чем речь.Где это посмотреть?

Comment: Если объявить очки и таймер как `const`, они не обнулятся.

Comment: @Suvitruf, будьте добры. Есть скрипт таймера. Что, где и как объявить const?

Comment: Расписал в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Внутри скрипта можно объявить эти поля как`static`.

Как-то так:

```
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour{
     private static int m_Points = 0; // набранные очки

     public int Points{
          get{return m_Pointsl;}
          set{m_Points = value;}
     }
     [...]
}
```

Теперь не зависимо от того, что вы там со сценой делаете, переменная `m_Points` не сбросится. Точно так же можно для таймера поступить.

Comment: спасибо большое! Я обошелся без перезагрузки сцены. Так правильнее. Вашу подсказку сохраню на будущее.